# Using document.getElementById() to load images in Rails

Tags: javascript, html

Wanting to use `document.getElementById()` to load images into HTML in Rails.

Section of HTML code

```
<div id="dealersCards">
    <span id = "D0"></span>
    <span id = "D1"></span>
    <span id = "D2"></span>
    <span id = "D3"></span>
    <span id = "D4"></span>
    <span id = "D5"></span>
    <span id = "D6"></span>
    <span id = "D7"></span>
</div>
```

Corresponding Javscript code

```
function displayPlayerOneInitialCards()
{
    length = dealerCards.length;
    for( dealerCount = 0; dealerCount < length; dealerCount++) 
    { 
        newCard = dealerCards[dealerCount]
        if(dealerCount == 0)
        {
            var cardToDisplay = newCard.cardFaceDown;
        }
        if(dealerCount == 1)
        {
            var cardToDisplay = newCard.cardToDisplay;
        }
        dealerIdName = 'D';
        dealerIdName   = dealerIdName  + dealerCount.toString();
        fileNameCard= '<img  width="80" height="128" src="images/'+ (cardToDisplay.trim())+'" alt="Card"/>';
        document.getElementById(dealerIdName).innerHTML = fileNameCard;
    }
}
```

Error message:

> No route matches [GET] "/game/BlackJack/images/H3.gif"

images are in `app/assets`.

Comment: Is there an image called exactly that, at that exact route in your file structure? As well - there should be something in front of that route, such as `localhost:3000/assets/...`.

Comment: The images are in are in app/assets/images. The <%= image_tag('C2.gif') %> works when put straight into the html. But I can't find a way to use fileNameCard= '<img  width="80" height="128" src="images/'+(cardToDisplay.trim())+'" alt="Card"/>';
  document.getElementById(dealerIdName).innerHTML = fileNameCard; to load the images. Using fileNameCard = <%= image_tag('C2.gif') %>; doesn't because its not a string

Comment: `src="images/'+(cardToDisplay.trim())+'"` - this isn't the whole file path. Your file path doesn't start at `images` it probably starts with 'localhost' or `example.com/images/...` A good way to find the asset would be to copy and paste the route it's saying isn't there - into the browser. Does an image appear? You can also inspect the image when you said it does appear, and look at what the route is.